# select and then insert in sqlite table

Tags: database, sqlite

I am trying to insert records into a sqlite table where in I have to first run a select query on the table and if the record does not exists then insert it.

Is there an efficient way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like `INSERT OR REPLACE` would suit you here aka `REPLACE` in MySQL.

See:

http://www.sqlite.org/lang_replace.html

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html